# Where did the rest of the Vision come from?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In Age of Ultron when

> Ultron and Dr. Helen Cho were creating the body that would become the Vision, she stated that the Vibranium was bonding with "the organic material".

Where did this material come from and and whose material was it?!

Comment: She demonstrated an ability to make very impressive organic material earlier in the film, which people comment on several times as being very realistic.  I assumed it was a similar process, hence her involvement.

Comment: I though she was making that from donor tissue. Although in hindsight, I think you are correct.

Comment: when she's working on Hawkeye she does say it's his own tissue, so it's a good question.

Comment: Woah, why the downvote? It clearly states that the vibranium is bonding to something, I wasn't sure exactly what it was.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Doctor Cho remarks her cradle was capable of creating synthetic organic material as "good as the real thing." This means the Vision is composed of synthetic flesh with a nanotechnological support system using Vibranium-augmentation in some as yet undisclosed manner.

- While she was perfectly capable of using her technology to replicate a person's personal flesh and DNA signature, she did state she could create new flesh using her cradle's technology.
- This means there was no need for a known donor. Either the flesh was cloned from some unknown person or it was created using whatever the nature of the process she had invented.
- This would jibe with the Vision's synthetic body in the Marvel Canon Universe, Earth-616, where his body was artificially created and given powers through some undisclosed process.